# Mutual Information from Multiple Sources

Tags: mutual-information, information-theory

The mutual information gain expression is

$$
H(X) - H(X | Y)
$$

If I have a set of data sources, $ \mathbf{X} = \lbrace X_0, X_1,\ldots,X_m \rbrace $, then I start with the simplest mutual information analysis I could think of: "Leave One Out" mutual information gain.

So, for each $X_i \in \mathbf{X}$, I calculate

$$
I_m = \lbrace H(X_i) - H(\mathbf{X}) : X_i \in \mathbf{X}\rbrace
$$

Where $I_m$ indicates "mutual information gain."

---

However, this seems like it would fail to capture deeper interactions with data sources.  Obviously, analyzing all possible combinations is exponential...

But is there a deeper, more robust way of handling "mutual information gain" in this context?

Perhaps a way to sample the various combinations?

Comment: Personally, I can't understand your question.

Comment: @AmiTavory oh, this is a standard topic in ML. I am using set builder notation in the latter part.

Comment: @AmiTavory for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_mutual_information

Comment: Sorry for the downvote (I'll be happy to reverse it if the question becomes clearer). The problem, IMHO, isn't with standard definitions in information theory or set notations, but with the clarity of the question itself: 1. (minor:) in "mutual information gain equation" I think you meant "expression", not "equation", 2. $I_m = ...$ does not appear to be related to mutual information, as it is a set of differences in entropies, not a set of differences between entropies and conditional entropies, 3. etc.

Comment: @AmiTavory note the bold font of the second X.  Conditional entropy is a difficult concept when dealing with a graph, so it seems like the most logical next step

Comment: @AmiTavory so, in a graph, a conditional entropy would seem to be no more or less than the same graph invariant with both sets of edges added to the graph.  I’ll add it into the question though because I see you are right, it is something I need to know about, and the question is confusing without it.  (In the morning though)

Comment: @AmiTavory in other words, $P(X|Y) = P(X)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  So, since $Y$ is adding edges to a graph, $P(X|Y) = P(X)$, and $H(X|Y) = H(X\cup Y)$, or is that wrong?

Comment: If $P(X|Y) = P(X)$, then $H(X|Y) = H(X)$, no?

Comment: @AmiTavory it is just impossible for an edge's presence to be non-independent of another edge.  I cannot think of an example where I provide two disjoint edge sets, and have them be conditional on each other. Perhaps conditionality would apply further up the chain (i.e., where I am deciding which edges are to be added to begin with).  But, yeah, I don't see how $X|Y$ has meaning in the context of the graph, and $H(X\cup Y) \neq H(X) + H(Y)$, given a particular invariant, so it seems reasonable to do what I have done, to me, and I am here asking the question, so obviously I have doubts.

Comment: @AmiTavory anyways, it is known that entropy is not well-defined for a graph; however, it does have meaning--people use it.  What I am looking for is a deeper hack to get the most out of this concept, in this domain.